# Goldstone's theorem and massless modes for $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, symmetry-breaking

Consider a scalar field doublet $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ with a Mexican hat potential

$$V~=~\lambda (\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2-a^2)^2.$$

When $a=0$ this is a quartic potential and the symmetry is not spontaneously broken. However when the field acquire a VEV, the fields splits into a massive mode and a massless boson mode called the [Goldstone boson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson).

I am wondering about the initial potential with $a=0$: does it have 2 massive modes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIR it has two massless modes, as there are no quadratic terms around the minimum.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: You should say that this requires fine-tuning, as the mass-term will renormalize away from zero. You need to fine-tune the $m^2$ to some negative value to get to the critical point.

Comment: Indeed, two massless modes, but neither is a Goldstone boson, as each transforms ***linearly*** into each other by the, now, unbroken  O(2) symmetry.